# MySQL Selecting first instance of username when using COUNT and MIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The following SQL code returns bookmarks, titles, urls etc. and sorts them by popularity or date posted, depending on which flag has been supplied.

It is also designed to ignore entries if the current logged in user or current ip address has chosen to block a particular bookmark.

```
$ip_address = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
$command = "SELECT cb.bookmark_id, cb.title, cl.username, 
           UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MIN(cb.date_posted)) AS date_posted, bu.url,
           cb.notes, count(cb.customer_id) AS popularity,
           count(fb.bookmark_id) AS flag_count FROM customer_bookmarks cb
           INNER JOIN customer_logins cl ON cb.customer_id=cl.customer_id
           INNER JOIN bookmark_urls bu ON cb.bookmark_id=bu.bookmark_id
           LEFT OUTER JOIN flagged_bookmarks fb ON bu.bookmark_id=fb.bookmark_id
           WHERE (fb.customer_id IS NULL OR
           !(fb.customer_id='".$db->real_escape_string($customer_id)."' 
           OR fb.ip_address='".$db->real_escape_string($ip_address)."')) AND
           cb.date_deleted<=0 GROUP BY cb.bookmark_id";
if ($flag == 'popular') {
    $command .= " ORDER BY popularity DESC";
}
else if ($flag == 'recent') {
    $command .= " ORDER BY date_posted DESC";
}
```

As it is, it currently returns correct results except that I get the most recent username of a user to post a bookmark and not the first one.

`Min(cb.date_posted)` selects the date of the first instance of a particular bookmark. `cb.customer_id` is the id of a user that has posted a bookmark, which is then used to obtain the corresponding username `(cl.username)`.

However the username which is returned does not match the first instance `Min(cb.date_posted)` but the most recent one to add an existing bookmark to their collection.

Does the `count(cb.customer_id)` which tallies the number of records of a particular `bookmark_id` have an effect on which username is returned?

What can be added to this code without drastically changing it or removing functionality to select the first username `cl.username`?

Comment: Please elaborate this "It is also designed to ignore entries if the current logged in user or current ip address has chosen to block a particular bookmark."

Comment: And why min() I dont think it is needed?

Comment: The first part of the `WHERE` clause checks the `flagged_bookmarks` table. If the id of the current user of the system `$customer_id` or their ip address has an entry in the `flagged_bookmarks` table that matches the current `bookmark_id` then this bookmark will not be shown to them.

Comment: The `min()` function is needed to sort all results by `date_posted`, as it gets the first date posted of each unique bookmark.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: Please have a look at the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-extensions.html). I cite: _MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause. This means that the preceding query is legal in MySQL. You can use this feature to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and grouping. [...] The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate._

Comment: Thanks VMai, I think that pretty much answers my question. It would appear that it is not possible to find the first instance of `cl.username` as it is not named in the GROUP BY clause and is a non-aggregated column, so MySQL will just pick a random value for this column. I may have to find another way, with a separate query to get this info.